# T-SQL IF-ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to do something like this with IF-ELSE, or something similar:

```
SELECT
MemberID,
ProfileTypeID
PrCountryID,    -- 3
PrStateID,      -- 4
PrStateInt
FROM Member
WHERE PrCity IS NOT NULL
IF @ShowUnclaimed = 'N'
    AND Claimed = 'Y'
    AND SBIcon = 'N'
END
AND Viewable = 'Y'
AND SystemID = 2
```

Many thanks in advance for any information.

neojakey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use Case for this one

```
SELECT
    MemberID,
    ProfileTypeID
    PrCountryID,    -- 3
    PrStateID,      -- 4
    PrStateInt
FROM Member
WHERE PrCity IS NOT NULL
AND Viewable = 'Y'
AND SystemID = 2
AND ( @ShowUnclaimed != 'N' 
      OR ( Clamed = 'Y' AND SBIcon = 'N' )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `case` expression ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx))

```
SELECT MemberID,
       ProfileTypeID
       PrCountryID,    -- 3
       PrStateID,      -- 4
       PrStateInt

FROM   Member

WHERE  PrCity IS NOT NULL
       AND CASE
               WHEN @ShowUnclaimed = 'N' AND Claimed = 'Y' AND SBIcon = 'N' THEN 1
           END = 1
       AND Viewable = 'Y'
       AND SystemID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention correctly there is no need for `IF`, or `CASE` for that matter.

Just something like this seems to be what you were trying to do...?

```
WHERE PrCity IS NOT NULL
AND (@ShowUnclaimed = 'Y'
    OR (Claimed = 'Y'
    AND SBIcon = 'N'))
AND Viewable = 'Y'
AND SystemID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try using `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    MemberID,
    ProfileTypeID
    PrCountryID,    -- 3
    PrStateID,      -- 4
    PrStateInt
FROM Member
WHERE PrCity IS NOT NULL
    AND Viewable = 'Y'
    AND SystemID = 2
    AND Claimed = CASE WHEN  @ShowUnclaimed = 'N' THEN 'Y' ELSE Claimed END
    AND SBIcon = CASE WHEN  @ShowUnclaimed = 'N' THEN 'N' ELSE SBIcon END
```

This is just one way to do it.  Best of luck.